Detect (indirect) left-recursion in a context-free grammar?
Given a context-free grammar:
A -> α0 | α1 | ...
B -> β0 | β1 | ...
...

It's straightforward to determine whether the grammar is directly left-recursive - it is, if any of the αi begin with A, or any of the βi begin with B, etc.
How can we detect if the grammar is indirectly left-recursive?

You can solve that by modelling the recursions.
Make a graph, where $A$ points to the beginning symbols of the $\alpha$'s. Etcetera.
Then detect cycles in that graph.
I have no clue whether the definition of indirect recursion allows whether $\alpha$ can be the empty string.
